# QEMU, how to install win2K as Guest from install-CD

Tags: windows, qemu, cd, guest-os

I have Guests-OS (Fedora etc) running fine with QEMU and u20.04 as the Host. I need to get some old pictures from an encrypted win2K backup CD. I have not found anything that will decrypt the huge backup file, so though I'd install win2K and give it a shot at it from when I created it. Yes, I am **that** old. :)

I dug out my original CD for win2K-SP4 and started the QEMU install using "Browse Local." Found the CD OK and I could see all the files on it including setup.exe.

I am at a loss as to what to select to get it started.

How do I install win2K as a QEMU-Guest from this install disk?

Comment: Hello. Seems that would be a good question for a Windows Forum.

Comment: Insert the Windows cd  in the virtual cd drive of your QEMU VM and change the boot order of the VM to boot it. As long as you have a virtual hard drive in that VM it’s much the same as installing to hardware

Comment: @David, what would they know about QEMU? Why is it so hard to just get an answer to a question. <-- rhetorical

Comment: @PonJar: OK, thanks, I will see what I can make work. I did not know there was a virtual CD not how to transfer the actual CD to it. I will give it some effort right now.

Comment: Apologies if you didn’t think you got the warmest of welcomes here. There are a lot of questions on here that do break forum rules. Yours is a bit grey because it’s possible to focus on the how to install Windows aspect and not the how to use a piece of Linux software running on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out -- very simple.

1: In virt-manager select "Local Install ..." and click "Forward."

2: Use the drop down and the CD should be at the bottom of that list, click it.

3: Follow through for a "normal" Guest install.